# Exception while updating Cache in POOrderEntry

Tags: acumatica

When a SOLine is added after creating the purchase order the values in SOLineSplit for "POType", "PONbr", "POLineNbr", "RefNoteID" is stored as NULL values.

When I add the same SOLine in a created Purchase order, I am trying to update the SOLineSplit NULL values with POLine values but I am getting an error in Pop up saying "Order Date Cannot be empty". Below is the code I have written in an event for updating values in Cache but getting an exception in graph.Actions.PressSave(); Can Anyone help me with this.

```
     public PXSelectJoin<SOLineSplit, InnerJoin<POOrder, On<SOLineSplit.orderType, Equal<POOrder.sOOrderType>,
                                                      And<SOLineSplit.orderNbr, Equal<POOrder.sOOrderNbr>>>>,
                                                      Where<SOLineSplit.pOType, IsNull, And<SOLineSplit.pONbr, IsNull>>> UnmappedSoLine;


    protected void POOrder_RowPersisted(PXCache sender, PXRowPersistedEventArgs e, PXRowPersisted BaseEvent)
    {


        POOrder row = e.Row as POOrder;
        if (row != null && e.TranStatus == PXTranStatus.Completed)
        {
            SOLinePartial graph = PXGraph.CreateInstance<SOLinePartial>();
            foreach (POLine poline in Base.Transactions.Select())
            {
                foreach (SOLineSplit sosplititem in UnmappedSoLine.Search<SOLineSplit.inventoryID>(poline.InventoryID))
                {
                    sosplititem.POType = poline.OrderType;
                    sosplititem.PONbr = poline.OrderNbr;
                    sosplititem.POLineNbr = poline.LineNbr;
                    sosplititem.OrderDate = poline.OrderDate;
                    SOLineSplit sp = PXSelectJoin<SOLineSplit,
                InnerJoin<POLine, On<
                SOLineSplit.pOType, Equal<POLine.orderType>,
                                And<SOLineSplit.pONbr, Equal<POLine.orderNbr>, And<SOLineSplit.pOLineNbr, Equal<POLine.lineNbr>>>>>,
               Where<POLine.orderNbr, Equal<Required<POOrder.orderNbr>>>>.Select(Base, row.OrderNbr);
                    if (sp != null)
                        sosplititem.RefNoteID = sp.RefNoteID;

                    graph.soLineSplit.Cache.Update(sosplititem);
                }


            }

            graph.Actions.PressSave();
        }          


    }
```

Comment: Doesn't the sales to purchasing linking logic fill in these values automatically? (When adding to an existing or new purchase order from sales order). Could have something to do with the graph you are using and the current SOOrder is null (based on SOLineSplit.OrderDate [PXDBDefault(typeof(SOOrder.orderDate))])

Comment: @Brendan This logic is different, so this is the scenario once the salesorder is created with SOLine with "Marked for PO" enabled, the Create purchase order action creates Purchase Order. After this I am adding a new SOLine in the Salesorder which creates NULL values in SOLineSplit. when the Same SOLine is created as POLine in Purchase order that is when I am trying to update the NULL values

Comment: even if you add the sales line to an existing PO? or do you have a custom process that adds a new line to the PO and auto links it to the sales line?

Comment: There is no custom process. Acumatica adds new PoLine for existing PurchaseOrder. But SoLineSplit values are empty when new SOLine is added.

Comment: my guess is SOLinePartial graph doesnt have a current value for SOOrder or your OrderDate value is empty. Ideally you would want to use rowinserted on PO and then on the POGraph cache the SOLinesplit change vs using a new graph.

Comment: First of all, you should move this code to the overridden `Persist` method and write the whole code in the `TransactionScope` so that you can be sure that if base `Persist` method fails then your code doesn't save anything to the database too. Also I think that you have to set `Current` Order before updating splits.